# Resetting Lock Screen after using 'lightdm-gtk-greeter' in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I'm fairly new to **Ubuntu** and I am using **16.04**. I used the `lightdm-gtk-greeter` to try and *change the lock screen wallpaper*, but it changed the whole theme, but only when I reboot or shutdown. I tried to uninstall `lightdm-gtk-greeter` using Terminal but that didn't work. Any way I can **reset the lock screen theme** back to the original when I reboot or shutdown? Thanks.